# MongoDB PHP - findOne, using query to filter results not working for a specific item

Tags: php, mongodb

**This is the Mongo collection I'm trying to test this on:**

```
{"_id":{"$id":"54d5002adc533bf41000002c"},"tasks":[{"taskID":1,"taskName":"Task 1 Name Here","subTasks":[1],"coords":{"gantt":{"x":10,"y":30},"pert":{"x":90,"y":100}}},{"taskID":2,"taskName":"Task 2 Name Here","participators":[1,2],"startDate":"5-12-2014","endDate":"5-21-2014"},{"taskID":3,"taskName":"Task 3 Name Here","subTasks":[3],"participators":[1]}],"participators":[{"participatorID":1,"participatorName":"Participator 1 Name Here"},{"participatorID":2,"participatorName":"Participator 2 Name Here"}]}
```

I'm trying to filter this data based on the ID and then only return back a certain set of tasks, filtering using the taskID.

**Here's the code I'm using:**

```
$cursor = $this->mongo->findOne(['_id' => $mongoID, 'tasks.taskID' => 2], ['_id' => false, 'tasks.taskID' => true, 'tasks.coords.gantt' => true]);
```

This should only return taskID 2's data; as you can see I'm trying to filter to only displaying taskID of 2. **But instead it returns:**

```
{"tasks":[{"taskID":1,"coords":{"gantt":{"x":10,"y":30}}},{"taskID":2},{"taskID":3}]}
```

I don't know how I'm meant to filter the results so only the specified taskID's data is returned.

Thank you.

**-- UPDATE --
Fixed using the following code:**

```
$cursor = $this->mongo->findOne(['_id' => $mongoID], ['_id' => false, 'tasks' => ['$elemMatch' => ['taskID' => 1]], 'tasks.coords.gantt' => true]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find an element in an array you need to use the [$elemMatch projection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/).

Comment: I changed the code to: `$cursor = $this->mongo->findOne(['_id' => $mongoID], ['_id' => false, 'tasks' => ['$elemMatch' => ['taskID' => 1]], 'tasks.coords.gantt' => true]);` and it works nicely! Thank you!